# Can Anyone Tell me whats the problem in my Android Studio Java Code... Trying to implement bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.alltasks:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cool", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Bottom_app.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/pending"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_task"
    android:title="App"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/Donetask"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_done_24"
    android:title="Done"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/alltasks"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_all"
    android:title="All Task"/>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_menu"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me why I am getting this error at the startup when my app start it crashes right away

> Process: com.imdigitalashish.vatodolistapp, PID: 2889
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.imdigitalashish.vatodolistapp/com.imdigitalashish.vatodolistapp.MainActivity}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML
> file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:513)
> at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:49)
> at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3528)
> at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
> at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6233)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
> at com.imdigitalashish.vatodolistapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

This is the error I am getting

Answer (score 1):

In your XML, you are using:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

A `<fragment>` tag **must** have an `android:name` that points to a valid Fragment class. The reason you're getting a `NullPointerException` is because you have not provided any fragment class to put into your `<fragment>` tag.

You can replace that tag with a `<FrameLayout>` if you just want an empty box without any initial fragment.

Comment: Thank You Very Much... Solved Thank You

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, make sure to hit the check mark next to the answer to accept the answer and remove your question from the list of unanswered questions. Best of luck going forward!

Comment: I have only 1 reputation so I can't do it.. It's not letting me